# How do i join 4 tables in sql

Tags: sql-server

Hi there I am a beginner in SQL coding and recently got an assignment from my teacher that I am not too sure how to do. If someone could help me by explaining what to do and how to do it.

The assignment is:

- As we have found the limitation of the 3 table system is that we can only order 1 product per order and we would need amend the demonstration database code to add an orderline table and insert data that would allow more than one product to be purchased per order.

Here is my code so far:

```sql
USE demonstrations;

DROP TABLE orders;
DROP TABLE customers;
DROP TABLE hotchillisauce;

CREATE TABLE customers(
    custid INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(50),
    lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    gender varchar(1),
    age INT,
    international VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO customers (firstname,lastname,gender,age,international)
VALUES 
('Doc','Marten','M',24,'Y'),
('Hifza','Memon','F',16,'N'),
('Graeme','Mitchell','M',56,'N'),
('Imaani','Joseph','F',17,'Y'),
('Fred','Smith','M',16,'N'),
('Eleanor','Bull','F',41,'Y');

CREATE TABLE hotchillisauce(
    prodid INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    product VARCHAR (100) not null,
    cost MONEY,
    qty INT
);

--data borrowed from www.chilliworld.com
INSERT INTO hotchillisauce(product,cost,qty) VALUES
('Blair''s After Death Sauce',5.99,3),
('Chilli Mafia Sir Raja (Sriracha) Sauce',2.99,16),
('Da'' Bomb Beyond Insanity',5.99,10),
('Dave''s Gourmet Hurtin'' Jalapeno Sauce',2.99,3),
('Dave''s Gourmet Insanity Sauce',5.99,2),
('Pete''s Dragon''s Blood Hot Green Salsa',4.99,5);

CREATE TABLE orders ( 
    orderid INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    customerid INT,
    productid INT,
    orderdate DATE,
    qty INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(customerid) REFERENCES customers(custid),
    FOREIGN KEY(productid) REFERENCES hotchillisauce(prodid)
);

INSERT INTO orders(customerid,productid,orderdate,qty)
VALUES
(1,1,'2018-07-02',3),
(1,2,'2018-08-23',4),
(2,1,'2018-08-14',2),
(3,4,'2018-10-07',5),
(4,3,'2018-11-30',9),
(2,5,'2018-12-04',11);
```

This is the query I got so far, I tried implementing the INNER JOIN however I have no idea how to do it.

```
DROP TABLE orders;
    
CREATE TABLE orders(
    orderid INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    customerid INT,
    orderdate DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY(customerid) REFERENCES  customers(custid),
);
    
INSERT INTO orders(customerid,orderdate)    
VALUES
    (1,'2018-07-02'),
    (1,'2018-08-23'),
    (2,'2018-08-14'),
    (3,'2018-10-07'),
    (4,'2018-11-30'),
    (2,'2018-12-04');
         
CREATE TABLE orderline(
    ordid INTEGER,
    productid INTEGER,
    qty INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (ordid) REFERENCES orders(orderid),  
    FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES hotchillisauce(prodid)
    
);
    
INSERT INTO orderline(ordid,productid,qty)
VALUES
    (1,1,3),
    (1,2,4),
    (2,1,2),
    (3,4,5),
    (4,3,9),
    (2,5,11);
        
SELECT o.ordid, o.productid, c.firstname, c.lastname, h.product, o.qty        
FROM orders as os, orderline as o, customers as c, hotchillisauce as h
WHERE os.orderid = o.ordid and h.prodid = o.productid and c.custid = os.customerid;
        --INNER JOIN orderline as o
        --on o.ordid = os.orderid
        --INNER JOIN hotchillisauce as h
        --on o.productid = h.prodid
        --INNER JOIN customers as c
        --on os.customerid = c.custid;
```

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like your orderline table should contain order id, product id and qty. Order id would be used to reference an order from the order table and that way many orderline rows could reference the same order. Joining them will be trivial by a JOIN clause.

Comment: I tried to improve the wording and formatting but the first bullet point appears to be incomplete; can you please review and probably [edit] to include the missing information, or rephrase it so it doesn't look like you forgot to finish the sentence?

Comment: @Shomz what do you mean by a JOIN clause, where would I use it exactly? Sorry to bother again

Comment: This is the JOIN clause: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx/  You'd use it when fetching results, for example, if you want to get all the products of an order.

Comment: @Offlin3 judging by trying to use `IDENTITY(1, 1)` in your create table statements you are talking about MSSQL Server not MySQL, they are completely different databases. Can you post what you have tried so far to write this query, no matter how small it may be?

Comment: @GharbadTheWeak I have posted the query that I have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

The commented section in your query looks alright, You used the old school fashion with the where caluse which can be replaced with the join clause, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    os.orderid,
    o.qty,
    h.prodid,
    c.custid  
FROM orders as os
INNER JOIN orderline as o on o.ordid = os.orderid
INNER JOIN hotchillisauce as h on o.productid = h.prodid
INNER JOIN customers as c on os.customerid = c.custid
```

A couple of remarks on your DDL tho !

- You need a PK for the "*orderline*" table.
- Change the "*hotchillisauce*" to a "*product*" table (it makes more sens)
- Use the same column name in the referenced table (naming conventions best practices)